# Writing a JUnit test case for a constructor

Tags: java, junit4

I have an assignment for school that involves learning how to use JUnit4. I need to make sure this constructor works properly, however, I am unsure of how to do so. There is a getter for the balance, so testing whether or not the constructor works with this is pretty easy, however, I don't know how to write a test case that involves user and pass as these do not have getters. Do I write a case for each individual parameter? Writing cases for methods that return a value hasn't been too difficult but I am clueless in terms of writing one for this constructor. Thanks!

```
public class BankAccount {

    // Starting balance
    private float balance = 0.0f;
    // Username and password
    private char[] username = null;
    private char[] password = null;


    public BankAccount(float balance, char[] user,char[] pass) {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.username = user;
        this.password = pass;
    }
}
```

Comment: The constructor has no logic besides setting up the fields. So the only thing you can test is that the same values passed into the constructor are accessible via getter methods.

Comment: Does the `BankAccount` class do anything? Are there any other methods that do something with `username` and `password` that you could use to confirm the right thing happens? Otherwise, and assuming there are no getter methods for those fields, the only option would be to use reflection to access their values.

Comment: IMHO it's not necessary to test the constructor, it will be tested (indirectly) when testing the exposed (non-private) methods.

Comment: There are no getters for username or password (I forgot to add this in the OP). Username and Password are used in other methods in the class, which is why I am confused as to why I need to test them directly with this constructor. As of right now it seems I can only test the balance. My thought process was along the lines of what "i.bondarenko" suggested, however, it's obvious without a getter for those variables it's not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you should write one test. You do not need write any more because it will be just duplicates. This test should control fields assignment:

```
@Test
public void propertiesAreSetOnBankAccountConstructor() {
    float balance = 100F;
    char[] userNameArray = {'u'};
    char[] passArray = {'p'};
    BankAccount testedObject = new BankAccount(balance, userNameArray, passArray);

    assertEquals(balance, testedObject.getBalance(), 0F);
    assertSame(userNameArray, testedObject.getUsername());
    assertSame(passArray, testedObject.getPassword());
}
```

**Update**:
If there are no getters you could use `org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils` (or just pure reflections):

```
@Test
public void propertiesAreSetOnBankAccountConstructor() {
    float balance = 100F;
    char[] userNameArray = {'u'};
    char[] passArray = {'p'};
    BankAccount testedObject = new BankAccount(balance, userNameArray, passArray);

    assertEquals(balance, ((Float)ReflectionTestUtils.getField(testedObject, "balance")), 0F);
    assertSame(userNameArray, ReflectionTestUtils.getField(testedObject, "username"));
    assertSame(passArray, ReflectionTestUtils.getField(testedObject, "password"));
}
```

Comment: I use `assertSame` because I want highlight that exactly this object (not a copy) is set to the field. It is more strict assertion.

Comment: If there is no getter for username or password I am assuming it's impossible to directly test these variables? Unfortunately this is the case as the only getter within the class that is given is one for balance.

Comment: You  could use `ReflectionTestUtils` or something like that. Have a look at updated answer, please.

Answer (score -2):

Refer this example.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import org.junit.Test; 
public class CalculatorTest {

    @Test
        public void constructorTest(){
        private Calculator c;
        c = new Calculator(4, 5);
        assertThat(9, is(c.sum()));
    }


}
```

Comment: Why use an instance variable instead of a local variable? And why test if an exception is thrown while this is not the use case? (The second case doesn't have anything to do with the question)

Comment: This is just a demo to perform test on constructor. Also ignore second case. I generally use mockito, so that is why I have used an instance variable.